# Hide url parameters on google search result

Tags: seo, google-search

Hello there i have a question about google search result.
I searched website on google and the result is just like following image:

[image]

I don't want to show parameter on google result. Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: What is the exact role of "stueck" parameter in this page ?

Comment: i don't know i just copied similiar result from google search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can hide parameters in Google.

Follow
Google Webmaster --> Crawl --> URL Parameters

after that click Configure URL parameters »

than click add parameters

add parameters which you want not to index in Google.

Regards

Comment: But if the parameter in case is important, i.e. has influence on content ?
Not showing in SERP is not the same as no indexing.

Comment: Yes, i want to hide query string not no indexing entire page. But no indexing will be the choice if there is no way to hide it.

Comment: Yes you've to accept this as solution, Because it is Google Statement. And it is the only way to block Google to cache parameters urls.

Comment: I can't believe it took your post for me to find that! Thanks @Tech9